# How to use Javascript function on input elements in a for loop. Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm working on a Django form that can calculate values in real time. I would like the javascript function to work for all rows which consists of 3 input fields each. I tried assigning each input field with an id followed by a forloop counter. I also looped through the function hoping that it will work for all the ids, a1,a2,a3... b1,b2,b3... c1,c2,c3...
However, the function only worked for the last row.

Here's the javascript I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  for (i = 0; i < {{ total_rows|safe }}; i++) {  
    $('input').keyup(function(){ 
        var firstValue  = Number($('#a'+i).val());  
        var secondValue = Number($('#b'+i).val());
        document.getElementById('c'+i).value = firstValue * secondValue;
    });
  }

</script>
```

Here's my template:

```
<form>
{% csrf_token %}
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th> 
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for item, amount in loop_list %}
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="a{{ forloop.counter }}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="quantity1" value="{{ item.quantity }}">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="b{{ forloop.counter }}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="unit_price1" value="{{ item.product.unit_price }}">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="c{{ forloop.counter }}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ amount }}" readonly>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding all inputs multiple times to multiple keyup handlers. However, you don't need to use the ids here; loop over the rows in JavaScript. I've simplified the markup a little here.

(You will, however, need to have unique `name`s per input if you are planning on POSTing this form back to Django!)

```
{% for item, amount in loop_list %}
<tr class="calc-row">
  <td>
    <input class="quantity" value="{{ item.quantity }}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="unit-price" value="{{ item.product.unit_price }}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="amount" readonly>
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

With the classes set, you can then bind to the quantity and unit price inputs only once, and have the event handler look up the elements per row.

```
$("input.quantity, input.unit-price").keyup(function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr.calc-row");
  var quantity = Number($row.find(".quantity").val());
  var unitPrice = Number($row.find(".unit-price").val());
  $row.find(".amount").val(quantity * unitPrice);
});
```